# XML шаблоны | Верстка

Tags: android, вёрстка, xml, themes, android-themes

Есть ли какие-то сайты например [этот](https://bootstraptema.ru), но для **xml**? Хочу создать простое приложение, но не хочется тратить много времени на верстку (потому что её придется учить).

Comment: прямо в Android Studio в визуальном редакторе верстайте - вам хватит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще при разработке приложений на android так или иначе придется столкнуться с созданием макетов в xml. Поэтому нет смысла в отсрочке изучения данного материала. Но тем не менее есть несколько путей в вашем случае:

1. При поиске туториалов вам может попасться какое-то интересное решение той или иной проблемы, и чаще всего в туториале есть пример разметки приложения которое создается. Вы можете взять xml оттуда и изменить под себя.
2. Есть например [такой](http://seotoolzz.com/free-android-app-templates/) сайт с кучей разных приложений, при загрузке вы скачиваете архив проекта где так кроме всего прочего будет xml который вам нужен. Вот еще несколько источников: [1](https://www.template.net/design-templates/android-app-design-templates/), [2](https://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-find-android-xml-templates-for-ui), [3](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/15-best-android-app-templates-of-2017--cms-29643).

Но стоит понимать, что даже если вы найдете идеальный макет, вам все-равно рано или поздно придется что-то изменить под себя. Эти знания нужны будут в будущем, поэтому я бы советовал изучить этот вопрос, вот например есть [видеоурок](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lUymjX4K7FM) по дизайну xml.

Comment: Я более-менее знаю xml, но писать самому все лень. Было бы хорошо, если бы существовало что-то вроде bootstrap для AS. И да, спасибо за источники, это то, что я искал.